# really grainy shadows

Tags: rendering

I am making a spaceship corridor in blender cycles, but when I render it out it gets really grainy in terms of shadows.[image: (as shown here)]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How many samples?

Comment: Try to increase the number of Samples.